# WCF call from remote web application

Tags: database, wcf

I'm new to WCF.  I've got a WCF service (VacationSickPayoutService) running on one website.  If I just declare, assign, and return a string, I can get the string from a remote website call to the WCF service - no problem.  But if, in that WCF service routine, I try and make a database call and then return a string value, it fails completely.  I'm sure I need some kind of authentication from the remote caller to allow the service to call the database?  I'm just using the same database login/call as a physical web user (human) would use if they were on the site and the database call was made.  I.e. the service uses the same functions.

Is there some change I could make to the web.config file on the service machine to allow the remote call to initiate a database call within the service routines?  This is the only reference I have to the WCF service in my web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="v11.0" />
        </parameters>
      </defaultConnectionFactory>
    </entityFramework>
```

Do I need reference to the actual WCF service (VacationSickPayoutService) in the web.config file or is this something more complicated?

Also, forgot to mention that in order to consume the service I Added the Service Reference in the remote web application so I could see the function call that returns the string.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Do you mean that when you test your services locally its fetches data from Db and returns the string but it does not work when you call the same service from some other web application?

Comment: Do you get an error message back or is there one in the event viewer or other logs?  It sounds like a permissions issue for the database.  What account is the WCF service running under?  Make sure that account has the proper permissions for the database.

Comment: The communication from WCF to DB is same as Web to DB. It make no difference that WCF service is called from web or any where. Just check for the DB authentication details of WCF service to the DB. Since it is working for web, it should work for WCF also.

Comment: All, thanks for the responses.  Amit, I can call the service locally or remotely and it works as long as I don't do a database call in the service function being called.  Tim, if I call the service locally w/database call I get back the data string.  If I call it remotely, I get back "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  I just added the WCF service to the web application, how would I check to see what account it would be running under? That sounds like a likely problem!  Ray, I agree that the WCF service should just look like any other web user, so it should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Authenticating to the database

You have three options for the credentials to use when calling the database from the WCF service. Which one you should use depends on where your service is being deployed.

1. SQL Account (i.e., a username + password in the DB connection string)
2. Integrated Authentication using the account that the WCF service is running under (e.g., a service account in your domain)
3. Integrated Authentication using impersonation (i.e., the call to the DB is made to look as if the service were actually the remote user who is calling the service)

Option 3 is only possible in an intranet with a domain, since the users, service, and DB all have to be aware of the domain. Option 2 is more common because it's much easier to set up and, generally, gives you the same security benefits. Option 1 is recommended only when you don't have a domain available that both your service and your DB are aware of.

Assuming you use option 2, you'll need to create a domain account for your service. Then, wherever you have the service hosted, you'll need to use that account. Normally a WCF service is hosted in either IIS, or sometimes in a self-hosted command-line application. If you're using IIS, you need to set the identity of your AppPool to be the domain account you created for the service. And finally you'll need to give your domain account the necessary access in the database (e.g., in SQL Server you'll need to create a server & database login for the account and then grant it table read access, etc.).

### Troubleshooting internal errors in the WCF service

When I started using WCF, I was doing a lot of blind debugging of errors, writing to log files, etc. Then I found this tool: [Service Trace Viewer Tool (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's the best way to analyze what is going wrong with a WCF service; it will capture *everything* that happens and let you search for the exceptions that are being thrown by, e.g., your data access code.

You may also want to set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults = true` while you are debugging, because that will (often) pass the detailed inner exception to your client so you can get some feedback that way. (Easier than bringing up the Service Trace Viewer Tool. :))

### What account is the service running under?

You could modify your string-returning service method to return the string value of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` to see what account the service is running under. ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Is it possible for me to use option 2 if I'm on a shared hosted computer such as with Discountasp?  I set up a user in IIS and than a user with the same name within SQL server and gave them read/write access.  Then I try the following:
    string[] rolesArray = { "admin" };
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
        new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(
        "GMreminder", "user"), rolesArray);
Just before the database call.  I'm not sure I'm approaching this correctly.

Comment: Lars, How about option 1?  I don't send the database user/password with the remote call, but I do access the SQL account in the WCF service using the db user/password in the connection string - just as it would be called if a web user where to go to the page and run the function. Any examples that you know of that would make use of that method?